# instance pool destroyed mongodb replicaset

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, replication, database-replication

I created a replica set with a primary, a secondary and an arbiter.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const url = 'mongodb://192.168.244.40:27017,192.168.244.38:27017,192.168.244.36:27017/mydb';

async function main() {
    let count = 1;
    console.log('connected to db');

    mongoose.model('testreplica', new mongoose.Schema({ name: String }));
    const olduc = new mongoose.model('testreplica')({name: 'uc'});
    await olduc.save();
    console.log('uc is: ', olduc);

    while(true) {
        console.log(`get uc, ${count}'th try`);
        count = count + 1;
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(async () => {
                const uc = await mongoose.model('testreplica').findOne();
                console.log(uc);
                resolve();
            }, 2000);
        });
    }
}

mongoose
  .connect(url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then((mongoose) => {
      main();
  });
```

I'm using mongodb v3.4 and node v16 and mongoose v5.6.9

192.168.244.40:27017 is the primary,192.168.244.38:27017 is the secondary,192.168.244.36:27017 is the arbiter.

when I stop the first instance, the secondary becomes primary and my code continues working; but when I start the first one again and it becomes primary again, code throws error and stops. error is:

```
/home/ap2015/jalil/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/sdam/server.js:301
    return new MongoError('server instance pool was destroyed');
           ^

MongoError: server instance pool was destroyed
    at basicWriteValidations (/home/ap2015/jalil/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/sdam/server.js:301:12)
    at basicReadValidations (/home/ap2015/jalil/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/sdam/server.js:308:17)
    at Server.command (/home/ap2015/jalil/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/sdam/server.js:209:19)
    at checkServer (/home/ap2015/jalil/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/sdam/monitoring.js:144:12)
    at /home/ap2015/jalil/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/sdam/monitoring.js:197:7
    at Pool.reset (/home/ap2015/jalil/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:767:39)
    at /home/ap2015/jalil/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/sdam/monitoring.js:195:19
    at /home/ap2015/jalil/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/sdam/monitoring.js:160:18
    at Server.command (/home/ap2015/jalil/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/sdam/server.js:211:14)
    at checkServer (/home/ap2015/jalil/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/sdam/monitoring.js:144:12)
    at Object.monitorServer [as monitorFunction] (/home/ap2015/jalil/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/sdam/monitoring.js:186:3)
    at Server.monitor (/home/ap2015/jalil/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/sdam/server.js:188:12)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/ap2015/jalil/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/sdam/topology.js:753:22)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) {
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}
```

also, when I stop the first one and second one becomes primary then I run the code, it gives this error:

```
node:internal/process/promises:279
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.244.40:27017
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1278:16) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}
```

what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Issue in `mongoose.connect()`add `autoReconnect = true`

```js
mongoose.connect(url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    autoReconnect: true
});
```

And you can add eventlistener for the `disconnect` event. when this event occur.
By using this code, mongoose will reconnect

```js
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () {
  mongoose.connect(url, { server: { auto_reconnect: true } });
});
```

Comment: this just retries connection, and it fixes the first problem, but when primary is down and I have 2 servers, if I restart the code it can't connect to the first instance and throws 'connection refused'